# alerbox with value from a list, done by a button

Tags: php, jquery, html

I m trying to get a id from a list by clicking on a button thats included in the list.The information in the list is generated from a openlayers map. The list is automatically generated from the map. The list looks like this. The id i want is the value of dans [image]

The code i m using is as following:

```
    <ul id ="table_overvieuw">
<#list features as feature>
  <li><b>Type: ${type.name}</b> (id: <em>${feature.fid}</em>):
  <ul>
  <#list feature.attributes as attribute>
    <#if !attribute.isGeometry>
      <li><b>${attribute.name}</b></li>
      ${attribute.value}
    </#if>
  </#list>
  <br><br>
 <input type="button" name="geef slijpplaten info" class="ok" value="OK" onclick="myFunction()" />
  </ul>
  </li>
</#list>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
function highlight(e) {
    if (selected[0]) selected[0].className = '';
    e.target.parentNode.className = 'selected';
}

var table = document.getElementById('table_overvieuw'),
    selected = table.getElementsByClassName('selected');
table.onclick = highlight;

function myFunction(){

    alert($("li.selected.value li:first" ).html());
}
</script>
```

The renderded html of the list is:

```
    <html><head>
<style>
ul {
    background: #cce5ff;
    padding: 20px;
}
ul li {
    margin: 5px;
}
.selected {
    background-color: brown;
    color: #FFF;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body><ul id="table_overvieuw">
  <li><b>Type: dans_compleet</b> (id: <em>dans_compleet.fid--50014eb6_15374e6dbd1_-779f</em>):
  <ul>
      <li><b>dans</b></li>
      40347
      <li><b>x_coord</b></li>
      221405
      <li><b>y_coord</b></li>
      591262
      <li><b>dans_code</b></li>
      40347
      <li><b>archis_onderzoeksmeldingsnr</b></li>
      21475 and 24639
      <li><b>title</b></li>
      De (on)mogelijkheden van archeologisch vriendelijk bouwen op terpen en wierden 
      <li><b>creator</b></li>
      Huisman, D.J.
      <li><b>contributor</b></li>
      Doesburg, J. van; Muller, A.; Stover, J.
      <li><b>date_created</b></li>
      2009
      <li><b>rights_holder</b></li>
      Rijksdienst voor het Cultureel Erfgoed
      <li><b>publisher</b></li>
      Rijksdienst voor het Cultureel Erfgoed
      <li><b>description</b></li>
      Bouwaanvragen voor de realisatie van nieuwbouw op de wettelijk beschermde archeologische monumenten Kenwerd  en Groot Wetsinge in de provincie Groningen vormden aanleiding in het kader van het MADE-project onderzoek te doen naar de mogelijke effecten van heien op wierdelagen en daarmee samenhangende grondsporen. Voorafgaande aan het heien zijn op beide locaties boringen gezet en proefsleuven gegraven om de stratigrafische opbouw te bepalen. Tevens zijn uit de profielen micromorfologische monsters genomen. In Kenwerd is er sprake van een wierde en in Groot Wetsinge van een valgen. Beide complexen lijken in de Late IJzertijd \xe2\x80\x93 Vroeg Romeinse tijd te zijn ontstaan. Nadat de heipalen waren aangebracht zijn opnieuw sleuven gegraven en daaruit micromorfologische monsters genomen. Op basis van de veldwaarnemingen en resultaten van de analyse van de slijpplaten kan worden aangenomen dat schade door ingeheide betonnen heipalen in beide gevallen slechts enkele centimeters buiten de paal zelf waarneembaar zal zijn. In algemene zin zal dit gelden voor alle terpen en wierden met een zelfde  samenstelling en structuur. Hier moet evenwel de volgende kanttekening worden geplaatst. Uit de waarnemingen in een slijpplaat uit Groot Wetsinge blijkt dat zandlagen w\xc3\xa9l laterale effecten van heipalen kunnen laten zien. Als zandlagen dikker zijn en niet, zoals in Groot Wetsinge het geval is,  kleilaagjes of -laminae bevatten, is de schade aanzienlijk groter. Dat geldt ook als het zand grover en/of hoekiger is. Daarnaast is het logisch dat een heipaal die door een bakstenen fundering, liggend hout of een compacte ,mestlaag wordt geheid, of die andere harde of taaie obstakels  raakt, veel grotere schade zal aanrichten.  Bij beslissingen over het al dan niet toestaan van heien op beschermde terpen en wierden moeten deze punten worden meegenomen.<br>Extrapolatie van de onderzoeksresultaten van Kenwerd en Groot Westinge naar andere gebieden is niet aan te raden. Terpen en wierden hebben een zeer specifieke samenstelling en genese. Het is daarom van groot belang om vergelijkbaar onderzoek uit te voeren in andere gebieden en op andersoortige vindplaatsen om die wijze uiteindelijk tot een algemener beeld te komen van de effecten van het gebruik van heipalen op terreinen met archeologische resten.<br><p></p>
      <li><b>subject_abr_complex</b></li>
      Nederzetting - Terp/wierde
      <li><b>temporal_abr</b></li>
      Middeleeuwen: 450 - 1500 nC and Nieuwe tijd: 1500 - heden
      <li><b>spatial_point</b></li>

      <li><b>spatial_coverage</b></li>

      <li><b>relation</b></li>
      Rapportage ARcheologische Monumentenzorg 176
  <br><br>
 <input type="button" name="geef slijpplaten info" class="ok" value="OK" onclick="myFunction()">
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
function highlight(e) {
    if (selected[0]) selected[0].className = '';
    e.target.parentNode.className = 'selected';
}

var table = document.getElementById('table_overvieuw'),
    selected = table.getElementsByClassName('selected');
table.onclick = highlight;

function myFunction(){

    alert($("li.selected.value li:first" ).html());
}
</script>  
</body></html>
```

If i click on my button(after selecting) i get dans and not the value of dans. Can somebody give me a hand?

Comment: It will be great if you can add the rendered HTML rather than the PHP code

Comment: cab you help me. what is excatly rendered html? i think it is the html that i can find in my console

Comment: ► Right click on page  ► Select view page source. ► Select your required portion from the page

Comment: Html code is not complete. What are you actually trying to achieve? You want to extract the text value of some element ?

Comment: yes, but i m getting the text between <li> and not the value

Comment: Can you wrap that inside a span or something. Without a proper container we wont be able to select it

Comment: could you provide this code in jsfiddle ?

Comment: jsfiddle is not possible because the values in the table are variable. Maybe i can alter the question in: how can i select a value in a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this is a bit of a slap-dash approach, with little changes that need to be made to your code, but it should get you what you want.

Firstly wrap `${attribute.value}` in `span` tags so we can select it in js/jquery. Then alter the `alert` in `myFunction()` to:

```
alert($("li.selected").next('span').html());
```

---

But I would recommend that you rethink your approach to this. I would have the values of the attributes, wrapped in `span` tags,  inside the `li` tags. This would then make the selection process of the selected `li` much easier (`$('li.selected span').html();`) and reliable as, currently, there is no real  guarantee that the next `span` is the corresponding value to the selected `li`.

Comment: thank you, it is working now but i will reconsider it